# VSCode: launch.json runtimeExecutable for Python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In VSCode launch.json configuration, is it possible or how can I config the "runtimeExecutable" property for Python files, for the "python" type?

In node.js files, something like this below does work

```json
{
    "type": "pwa-node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "nodejs nodemon",
    "program": "${file}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/nodemon",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "-e",
        "js,mjs"
    ]
},
```

The above uses the program file as specified with the "program" property, so the value will be used for this.
But the "program" value is actually not necessary here, since you can pass the file in this way below, specifying the file in the runtimeArgs option.

```json
{
    "type": "pwa-node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "nodejs nodemon",
    // "program": "${file}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/nodemon",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "-e",
        "js,mjs",
        "--exec",
        "C:/ProgramData/nvm/v16.6.0/node64.exe ${file}"
    ]
}
```

So now I wanted to have a similar project to the above node.js project, but in Python.
I wrote the below, I thought I would work, but it doesn't.

The below outputs a VSCode error message `Invalid message 'either "program", "module", or "code" must be specified'`, and I cannot omit the program property.
If I add the program property, the config ignores the runtimeExecutable property and runtimeArgs property entirely, and runs python (it should be "mitmproxy" here). So it outputs a python error as I could expect.

```json
{
    "name": "python mitmproxy",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    // "program": "${file}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/../venv/bin/mitmproxy",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "--mode", 
        "upstream:https://localhost:3148", 
        "--listen-port",
        "8085", 
        "--scripts", 
        "./mitmproxy_main.py"
    ],
},
```

So, the runtimeExecutable is not exist for Python on VSCode? Or I'm doing wrong code, or specifying a runtime executable (like a pip executable as this case) for python is not possible? Thanks.

Comment: python launch configs use `program` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, so as I've solved the issue thanks to @rioV8 's comment, I found there are mainly two misunderstandings I had regarding of this matter.

1. Wrong: The VScode config properties are same among langauges, python/node.js etc

While in node.js it uses `runtimeExecutable` to specify a globally installed node.js package, in python it uses `module` to specify a installed python module.

The `runtimeArgs` for node.js and the `args` for python is the same case.

2. Wrong: pip does always install modules

pip does not always install modules. but sometmes it does install a executable python script, or may not contain its module.

So in this case, `pip install mitmproxy` does not enable you to run `python -m mitmproxy` kind of commands. But instead it does allow you to run `python ./venv/bin/mitmproxy`.

Here cautiously note that it's not `python mitmproxy` but `python ./venv/bin/mitmproxy`, specifying the full or relative path to the executable python script. I found this part is a little tricky since you can run `mitmproxy` as the virtualenv paths to the bin for you, but it does not for `python [file]`.

---

So in sum up, the following launch.json did work for me.

It expands a command basically like `./../venv/bin/python ./../venv/bin/mitmproxy --mode upstream:https://localhost:3148 ...and more`.

```json
// working config
{
    "name": "python mitmproxy",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    // "program": "${file}",
    // "program": "mitmproxy",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/../venv/bin/mitmproxy",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "args": [
        "--mode",
        "upstream:https://localhost:3148",
        "--listen-port",
        "8085",
        "--scripts",
        "./mitmproxy_main.py"
    ]
},
```

When the installed pip package is a "module" unlike this case, you must specify `module` instaled of `program`. (I haven't tested this myself but it should work)

So the below would expand a command like `python -m mitmproxy --mode ...and more`.

```json
// wrong config
{
    "name": "python mitmproxy",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "module": "mitmproxy",
    "args": [
        "--mode",
        "upstream:https://localhost:3148",
        "--listen-port",
        "8085",
        "--scripts",
        "./mitmproxy_main.py"
    ]
},
```

Comment: why don't you put the `venv` as a subdir of the workspace, then VSC will detect it and activate it. Maybe if you set the python path setting VSC will also see it is a venv and activate it